# How to speed up insertion from pandas.DataFrame .to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Hello i am currently trying to write data from four pandas data frame to mysql on my local machine , my machine is taking 32 seconds  for inserting  20,000 records (5000 for each table) Code-

tables - 
1) posts
2) post_stats
3) post_languages
4) post_tags

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:dbase@123@localhost/testDb")

startTime=time.time()

dfstat.to_sql('post_stats', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
for i in range(0, dfp.shape[0]):
ss = str(dfp.iloc[i][0])
sss = 'Select id from post_stats where post_id =\"%s\"' % (ss)
#print(sss)
rss = engine.execute(sss)
x = rss.fetchone()
dfp['stats_id'][i] = x[0]
dfp.to_sql('posts', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
dfl.to_sql('post_languages', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
dftagv.to_sql('post_tags', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)


endTime=time.time()
diff=endTime-startTime 
print(diff)
```

Currenlty i am storing the data in my local machine but in future i have to send data over to mysql server , Is there any way to speed up insertion
or is there any different approach so that i can store data at a faster rate like using bulk insert. please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is for each row an insert query is made, then before next row insert it waits for ACK.

Try running this snippet before `import pandas as pd`

```
from pandas.io.sql import SQLTable

def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
    print("Using monkey-patched _execute_insert")
    data = [dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement().values(data))

SQLTable._execute_insert = _execute_insert
```

This is a patch by [nhockham](https://github.com/nhockham) on to_sql insert which inserts line by line. [Here's the  github issue.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8953)

If you can forgo using pandas.to_sql I suggest you try sql-alchemy bulk insert or just write script to make a multirow query by yourself.

Edit:
To clarify we are modifying _execute_insert method of Class SQLTable in pandas.io.sql 
So this has to be added in the scripts before import pandas module.

The last line is the change.

`conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)` has been changed to :

`conn.execute(self.insert_statement().values(data))`

The first line will insert row by row while last line will insert all rows in one sql statement.

Update: For newer versions of pandas, we will need a slight modification of the above query.

```
from pandas.io.sql import SQLTable

def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
    print("Using monkey-patched _execute_insert")
    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    conn.execute(self.table.insert().values(data))

SQLTable._execute_insert = _execute_insert
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a little bit , i checked that issue earlier i am not able to understand the working of the above code

Comment: Run this snippet before you insert pandas module. That's all.

Comment: thanks man executemany worked , i was able to reduce the time from 32 seconds to 1.2 seconds

Comment: Sure. possibly comment on this issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8953 . if you'd like this feature to be part of pandas.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with SQL database as used by the "Kintone" service provided by Cybozu (popular in Japan but not really anywhere else) :(
 In any case great idea and hope it helps many others. `CompileError: The 'kintone' dialect with current database version settings does not support in-place multirow inserts.`