# 'SQLTable' object has no attribute 'insert_statement'

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am setting up a new computer at work, and after installing anaconda and other various packages I have on my other computer, I am attempting to run some code that works fine on my other computer.

However, when trying to use SQLalchemy to import into redshift, I am getting a new error that I can't find anything on via google:

'SQLTable' object has no attribute 'insert_statement'

this appears to be some issue with padas.io.sql but I have no clue what

here is the code block:

```
import io
from pandas.io.sql import SQLTable

def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
    print("Using monkey-patched _execute_insert")
    data = [dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement().values(data))

SQLTable._execute_insert = _execute_insert

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

dbschema='xref'
engine = create_engine('not_showing_you_this_part',
                              connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})
# test
from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine
@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
        cursor.commit()
# end test
api_start_time = time.time()
print('starting SQL query')
# change yh to the dataframe you want to upload
# under name = : enter in the name of the table you want to create or append to
df.to_sql(name='computer_test', con = engine, if_exists = 'append',index=False)
print('sql insert took: ' + str((time.time() - api_start_time)) + ' seconds')
```

for reference, the monkey-patch part is from:
[How to speed up insertion from pandas.DataFrame .to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927213/how-to-speed-up-insertion-from-pandas-dataframe-to-sql)

full error in image

[image]

Comment: The question that you source the monkey-patch from has the answer in it. Look at the last code snippet of the accepted answer, specifically: `conn.execute(self.table.insert().values(data))`

Answer (score 0):

I kept on searching for the answer, only to see that a gentlemen had answered you question in the comment section.

I was using a very similar code for connecting and inserting to Redshift.
And the mistake I was committing was to use the below
conn.execute(self.insert_statement().values(data))

Replace the above with the code below:

```
conn.execute(self.table.insert().values(data))
```

Shoutout to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6560549/supershoot for answering it in the comments.